# Selenium: element on PhantomJS never become visible

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I wrote this simple test code, which click on an element only when it is fully loaded:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://watch.nba.com/")

team = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@title='Bucks']")

over = team.find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_class_name("watchgame")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of(over))

over.click()
```

The code works propertly, so I copied it in my real code, substituting the first line with:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

The problem is that now the element *over* never become visible, and I Always get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException

even if increase the wait time.

I also read that with PhantomJS elements don't need to be visible, but *present*, so I wrote this:

```
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "watchgame")))

    over.click()
```

But this time I get:

> ElementNotVisibleException

Can you help me?

Comment: I have worked with PhantomJS a bit. I did observe the URL. Can you let me know the steps you are trying so that I can try to help you out?

Comment: It's actually pretty simple: find the match of the team selected (in this case 'Bucks'), and open the match page.

Comment: When I run `"//*[@title='Bucks']"` in the browser, it comes back with nothing. Be specific and detailed... what manual steps are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you mean with "run  in the browser"?

Comment: I used that piece of code to search every element with title = 'Bucks', which is the team name. So you can substitute it with any other team present on the page. (For example today you can try with 'Hawks')